# How to get aws dynamodb ConsumedCapacity in node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I seen aws document and i have insert parameter ReturnConsumedCapacity but not response ConsumedCapacity object... (use dynamodb local)

What was the mistake I made?

```
var params = {};
params.TableName = this.tableName;
params.Limit = 100;
params.ReturnConsumedCapacity = "TOTAL";
var items = [];
    var scanExecute = function() {
      dynamo.scan(params, function(err, result) {
        console.log(result); // not found ConsumedCapacity...
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          callback(new Error('dynamo scan error'));
        } else if (result.Count === 0) {
          callback(null, undefined);
        } else {
          items = items.concat(result.Items);
          if (result.LastEvaluatedKey) {
            params.ExclusiveStartKey = result.LastEvaluatedKey;
            scanExecute();
          } else {
            callback(null, items);
          }
        }
    });
  }
  scanExecute();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run the DynamoDB local instance, the consumed capacity will not be tracked.

> Consumed capacity units are not tracked. In operation responses, nulls
>   are returned instead of capacity units.

Comment: Good. Would you like to up vote so that it will be helpful for others.